Дайте код на смену обоев на андроид
Здрасте делаю приложение с каталогом обоев,нужен код на смену обоев телефона,кто может помогите пожалуйста.
Буду благодарен
Sketchware

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
